# jQuery drop down menu - hide inner ul when user clicks anywhere outside inner ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a jQuery drop down menu and everything works well except when the user clicks outside of the inner ul (e.g. the rest of the `body` or document) the inner ul does not pull back up. Any ideas? Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cp-nav ul li").click(function() {
        $("#cp-nav ul ul").slideUp("fast", function(){});

        $("ul", this).slideDown("fast", function(){
            $("ul", this).slideUp("fast");
        });
    });
});
```

So maybe do something like:

```
$("ul", !this).slideUp("fast", function(){});
```

I am kind of new to jQuery and JavaScript, and I tried to look around for my problem but it's kind of difficult to phrase. I also noticed there is a `callback` function for jQuery's `slideUp`, and I can not figure out how to use it. Any help? It would be much appreciated! :-)

## Edit

**HTML:**

```
<nav id="cp-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="products.html">Products</a>
            <ul>
               <li>Design Platforms</li>
               <li>3D Animation</li>
               <li>Graphic Design</li>
               <li>Python</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="products.html">About</a>
            <ul>
               <li>Company History</li>
               <li>CEO &amp; Founder</li>
               <li>etc.</li>
               <li>etc.</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="products.html">etc.</a>
            <ul>
               <li>etc.</li>
               <li>etc.</li>
               <li>etc.</li>
               <li>etc.</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: can you also post some part of the menu html ?

Comment: Umm, sure if it helps. Btw, your answer works, it's just making me wait 5 minutes to accept it. :b

Comment: Well depending on the html structure @gdoron's answer could also be a solution and it is simpler than mine.. / or mine might not always work.. so in general the more relevant info you provide, the better answers you will get..

Comment: I see. It is a very simple drop down structure. I was gonna just use CSS but I decided I wanted the user to click the element for the drop down instead of hover.

Comment: ok. Then you should also cancel the default action or the links will be followed.. `.preventDefault()` on the `event` of the click handler..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cp-nav").click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation(); // this stops the bubbling from going any higher
    });
    $('body').click(function(){ // this is only reached if the clicks comes outside the #cp-nav
        $("#cp-nav ul ul").slideUp('fast');
    });
    $("#cp-nav ul li").click(function() {
        $("#cp-nav ul ul").slideUp("fast", function(){});

        $("ul", this).slideDown("fast", function(){
            $("ul", this).slideUp("fast");
        });
    });
});
```